# Fabric env.roledefs not acting as expected

Tags: python, fabric

On the [fabric website](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html), this example is given:

```
from fabric.api import env

env.roledefs = {
    'web': {
        'hosts': ['www1', 'www2', 'www3'],
        'foo': 'bar'
    },
    'dns': {
        'hosts': ['ns1', 'ns2'],
        'foo': 'baz'
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation, this setup should give the env dict key 'foo' the value 'bar' when executing on hosts 'www1', 'www2', 'www3'. I cannot get this behavior, though fabric does correctly determine hosts. An example fabfile:

```
env.foo = 'WRONG'
@task()
def set_role():
    env.roles.append('web')

@task()
def print_foo():
    print env.foo
```

The example command:

```
fab set_role print_foo
```

Unexpected output:

```
[www1] Executing task 'print_foo'
WRONG
[www2] Executing task 'print_foo'
WRONG
[www3] Executing task 'print_foo'
WRONG

Done.
```

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this? How can I make it so that one server sees a different value for a key then another without too much trouble?

I am using fabric 1.10.0

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm using the latest Fabric (1.10.1) and have the same issue. the 'foo': 'bar' keys don't appear to be accessible, and the fabric documentation doesn't give any examples of how to use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confused by this too. It turns out that it is going to be possible to access these in Fabric 1.11:
https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1276

Comment: This is not true: Fabric 1.11 is out, the behavior has not changed and the issue has been closed

Answer (score 3):

Two issues, first the version of fabric in use is older than the dictionary-based definitions so it interprets the keys as host names.  This can be fixed by upgrading to >= fabric 1.10.0.  Second, the settings defined here don't populate env automatically, but if you use a task to set roles, it may be possible to set these like this:

```
@task
def set_role(role_name):
    env.roles.append(role_name)
    for k, v in env.roledefs[role_name].iteritems():
        if k == 'hosts':
            continue
        env[k] = v
```

Invoked with:

```
fab set_role:dns do_my_task
```

Comment: So if settings defined by roledefs don't populate automatically, what are they there for? Seems like this functionality would be there for a reason, even if undocumented?

Comment: So they're available to you, the programmer, without the need of an external config system.

Comment: But just defining your own dict and holding keys seems simpler and less code than the custom function and looping you suggested here. I wouldn't imagine they created this more cumbersome system to handle additional settings in that fashion

Comment: My question was related to the most recent version of fabric and still stands as of version 1.10.1. You cannot upgrade. Please read, research, and revise your answer.

Comment: Hi Aaron, sorry you misunderstood.  I said "upgrading to >= fabric 1.10.0", which 1.10.1 qualifies for.  There's nothing to change as my answer is valid for the latest version of fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Just an answer to this:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'prod': {
        'hosts':['server1','server2'],
        'path':'/opt/prod'
        },
    'stag': {
        'hosts':['server3','server4'],
        'path':'/opt/stag'
        }
}

@roles('prod')
def runa():
    role = env.effective_roles[0]
    print env.roledefs[role]['path']
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the extra roledef keys automatically set in `env` for a given task you can use a decorator. Here's the one I'm using:

```
from functools import wraps

def apply_role(f):
    "Decorator to apply keys in effective roledef to current env."
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if env.effective_roles:
            for k, v in env.roledefs[env.effective_roles[0]].items():
                if k in env and isinstance(env[k], list) and isinstance(v, list):
                    env[k].extend(v)
                elif k in env and isinstance(env[k], list):
                    env[k].append(v)
                else:
                    env[k] = v
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then decorate any task for which you want to have your roledef keys applied:

```
@apply_role
def mytask():
    ...
```