# How to use additional env.roledefs keys in Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813995/fabric-env-roledefs-not-acting-as-expected) I have been trying to access the additional keys in env.roledefs that Fabric provides:

```
from fabric.api import env

env.roledefs = {
    'web': {
        'hosts': ['www1', 'www2', 'www3'],
        'foo': 'bar'
    },
    'dns': {
        'hosts': ['ns1', 'ns2'],
        'foo': 'baz'
    }
}
```

However [the documentation](http://fabric-docs.readthedocs.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html) doesn't explain how to access those 'foo' keys. It seems super hacky to have to access them via:

```
env.roledefs[env.effective_roles[0]]['foo']
```

Is there an easy way to access these extra keys provided by Fabric?

Comment: Apart from it being ugly are there any problems with accessing the keys this way? Nothing hacky about it, just nested dicts..

Comment: Well you can access 'env.hosts' and it will hand you right back 'ns 1, ns2' (if 'dns' is your current role), but you can't access env.foo for some reason. Also effective_roles is a list so could be multiples in there which means then you need to loop over each one and handle accordingly, so that adds more code. Thought maybe there was a cleaner method with less boilerplate as that is sort of the point of Fabric.

Comment: Well, the looping is inevitable because all your roledefs have different 'foo's that will have to be handled. It is a bit confusing in that docs that they give you this foo, but not add the keys in there to the env object. However, since they don't really know what you will put in there it is not strange that they are not trying to do something to smart with it.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric should be making this a callable on env that you can refer to like: `env.foo`; on any roledef that has this in it's dict.

Comment: So you're saying it's a bug since you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easier way provided by fabric as of 1.11.1 (and seeing that the [related issue #1276](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1276) has been closed this may not change).

If you want to have those extra keys automatically set in `env` for a given task you can use a decorator. Here's the one I'm using:

```
from functools import wraps

def apply_role(f):
    "Decorator to apply keys in effective roledef to current env."
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if env.effective_roles:
            for k, v in env.roledefs[env.effective_roles[0]].items():
                if k in env and isinstance(env[k], list) and isinstance(v, list):
                    env[k].extend(v)
                elif k in env and isinstance(env[k], list):
                    env[k].append(v)
                else:
                    env[k] = v
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then decorate any task for which you want to have your roledef keys applied:

```
@apply_role
def mytask():
    ...
```